# How to find MySQL rows based on sum of values on adjacent dates?

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains time entries for different employees, across different dates, and the activity which their time is recorded against. I want to find all rows where they have a minimum amount of time spent on the same activity within, for example, a 3 day period.

Here's a simplified version of the table which I'll be querying:

```
CREATE TABLE `time_entries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `activity_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `work_date` date NOT NULL,
  `time_spent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Time, in minutes, spent on the current activity',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And some sample data:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| id | employee_id | activity_id | work_date  | time_spent |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 10 |           1 |           2 | 2016-06-11 |        120 |
| 16 |           1 |           3 | 2016-06-21 |        450 |
| 29 |           1 |           4 | 2016-06-22 |        450 |
| 17 |           1 |           4 | 2016-06-23 |        450 |
| 12 |           3 |           4 | 2016-06-23 |        450 |
|  4 |           1 |           4 | 2016-06-24 |        450 |
| 22 |           1 |           4 | 2016-06-26 |         60 |
|  9 |           1 |           6 | 2016-06-27 |        450 |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

The *time_spent* is in minutes, and I essentially want to select all rows which form a block of at least 3 days, with *time_spent* = *n* days* 450 minutes spent, on the same *activity_id* and *employee_id*

In the example above, I want to retrieve rows 29, 17, 4. Row 16 would not be included as this is a different *activity_id*, nor would row 12 as this is a different *employee_id*. Row 22 misses a date and therefore would 'break' the dates.

I guess I could create a view or temporary table to give me a sequence of dates, and use some aggregate functions to group the rows based on the *SUM(`time_spent`)* where the work_date is between the given date and *`work_date` + 3 days*

It's not really something I've had to achieve before now, but thinking about it, could form a useful tool for analysis in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following schema from you and my test data:

### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `time_entries` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `activity_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `work_date` date NOT NULL,
  `time_spent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Time, in minutes, spent on the current activity'
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

### Test Data

Please note that for simplicity on constructing test data, I use auto increments and allow the db to assign the id. As opposed to inserting the id's directly. I did show the id number to the far right, below, such as `-- 7`

```
insert time_entries(employee_id,activity_id,work_date,time_spent) values
(1,2,'2016-06-11',120), --  1
(1,3,'2016-06-21',450), --  2
(1,13,'2016-06-21',450), -- 3
(1,14,'2016-06-21',450), -- 4
(1,15,'2016-06-21',450), -- 5
(1,4,'2016-06-22',450), -- 6
(1,4,'2016-06-23',450), -- 7
(3,4,'2016-06-23',450), -- 8
(1,4,'2016-06-24',450), -- 9
(1,16,'2016-06-25',450), -- 10
(1,17,'2016-06-25',450), -- 11
(1,4,'2016-06-26',60), -- 12
(1,6,'2016-06-27',450), -- 13
(3,4,'2016-06-27',450), -- 14
(3,4,'2016-06-28',450), -- 15
(3,4,'2016-06-29',450), -- 16
(4,4,'2016-06-28',200), -- 17
(4,4,'2016-06-29',200), -- 18
(4,4,'2016-06-30',200), -- 19
(4,4,'2016-07-01',200), -- 20
(4,4,'2016-07-03',200), -- 21
(5,4,'2016-07-08',200), -- 22
(5,4,'2016-07-09',200), -- 23
(5,4,'2016-07-10',200), -- 24
(5,4,'2016-07-12',200), -- 25
(5,4,'2016-07-13',200), -- 26
(5,4,'2016-07-14',200), -- 27
(5,4,'2016-07-15',200), -- 28
(6,6,'2016-08-01',500), -- 29
(6,6,'2016-08-02',500), -- 30
(6,6,'2016-08-04',500), -- 31
(6,6,'2016-08-05',500), -- 32
(7,6,'2016-08-21',500), -- 33
(7,6,'2016-08-22',500), -- 34
(7,6,'2016-08-23',500), -- 35
(7,6,'2016-08-25',500), -- 36
(7,6,'2016-08-26',500); -- 37
```

### Final Query

```
select distinct t4.id,t4.employee_id,t4.activity_id,t4.work_date,t4.time_spent
from time_entries t4
join
(   select t3.id,t3.employee_id,t3.activity_id,t3.work_date
    from time_entries t3
    join
    (   select t1.id,count(*) as rowcount,sum(t2.time_spent) as timeworked
        from time_entries t1
        join time_entries t2
        on t2.employee_id=t1.employee_id 
        and t2.activity_id=t1.activity_id 
        and datediff(t2.work_date,t1.work_date)<=2
        and t2.work_date>=t1.work_date
        group by t1.id
        having rowcount=3 and timeworked>=450
    ) xDerived1
    on t3.id=xDerived1.id
) xDerived2
on t4.employee_id=xDerived2.employee_id 
and t4.activity_id=xDerived2.activity_id
and datediff(t4.work_date,xDerived2.work_date)<=2
and datediff(t4.work_date,xDerived2.work_date)>=0
order by t4.employee_id,t4.activity_id,t4.work_date;
```

### Results

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| id | employee_id | activity_id | work_date  | time_spent |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  6 |           1 |           4 | 2016-06-22 |        450 |
|  7 |           1 |           4 | 2016-06-23 |        450 |
|  9 |           1 |           4 | 2016-06-24 |        450 |
| 14 |           3 |           4 | 2016-06-27 |        450 |
| 15 |           3 |           4 | 2016-06-28 |        450 |
| 16 |           3 |           4 | 2016-06-29 |        450 |
| 17 |           4 |           4 | 2016-06-28 |        200 |
| 18 |           4 |           4 | 2016-06-29 |        200 |
| 19 |           4 |           4 | 2016-06-30 |        200 |
| 20 |           4 |           4 | 2016-07-01 |        200 |
| 22 |           5 |           4 | 2016-07-08 |        200 |
| 23 |           5 |           4 | 2016-07-09 |        200 |
| 24 |           5 |           4 | 2016-07-10 |        200 |
| 25 |           5 |           4 | 2016-07-12 |        200 |
| 26 |           5 |           4 | 2016-07-13 |        200 |
| 27 |           5 |           4 | 2016-07-14 |        200 |
| 28 |           5 |           4 | 2016-07-15 |        200 |
| 33 |           7 |           6 | 2016-08-21 |        500 |
| 34 |           7 |           6 | 2016-08-22 |        500 |
| 35 |           7 |           6 | 2016-08-23 |        500 |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

About half the rows qualify. Based on the requirement of "showing the rows where ..." it could, say, show rows such that if there are 4 days in a row (for a given worker / activity / sum of hours), more than 3 could appear in the results. Meaning, if there was a block of 4, the first 3 could qualify, and the last 3 could qualify. That is shown in the results.

---

For a visualization of xDerived1, see the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, @Drew - this woks a treat! I restricted the date ranges as there're over half a million rows and it was taking an age to run.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of solving it, ordering the innermost subquery and using variables to link consecutive entries together before selecting groups of more than three. I have to say though, I think I prefer Drew's solution.

```
SELECT t4.* FROM time_entries t4
JOIN
(SELECT employee_id, activity_id, MIN(work_date) min, MAX(work_date) max FROM
    (SELECT t.id,
            @employee_id := t.employee_id employee_id,
            @activity_id := t.activity_id activity_id,
            @work_date := t.work_date work_date,
            @i i
        FROM (SELECT * FROM time_entries ORDER BY employee_id, activity_id, work_date) t
        JOIN (SELECT @employee_id := 0, @work_date := NULL, @i := 0) tmp
        WHERE 
        CASE WHEN @employee_id = employee_id
              AND @activity_id = activity_id
              AND work_date = DATE_ADD(@work_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
             THEN @i ELSE @i := @i + 1 END) t2
    GROUP BY t2.i, t2.employee_id, t2.activity_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3) t3
WHERE t4.employee_id = t3.employee_id
  AND t4.activity_id = t3.activity_id
  AND t4.work_date BETWEEN t3.min AND t3.max;
```